# Elasticsearch - Restore document level

Tags: elasticsearch, backup-strategies

Restoring from backup snapshot would be the best solution based on documentation.
Can we restore document level in Elasticsearch?

Thankyou.

Comment: What you're asking is really not clear. Do you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: i have experience in restoring snapshot /indexes, is it possible restore document rather snapshot?

Comment: Restore a document from where?

Comment: To be honest not sure from where i can restore, i 'm just checking is there any possibility.